# Zabbix. How to find out if trigger function is active

Tags: postgresql, zabbix

I have trigger on event when replication lag is over 40GB.
When it triggers, event.value in database becomes 1 and when it lag is less 40GB,
then another row in table zabbix.events is stored with value 0.

I'd like to start procedure in Postgres BD on cron every day, which calculate
what time LAG was over 40GB. So I have to count time diff between
when value was 1 and when 0.
But every day in procedure I have to guess, if trigger was activate with value 1
previous day and Lag is now over 40GB.
I think in Zabbix DB should be a sign if event is closed or active.

Suggest, please, where in DB is a sign if event is not closed

Comment: you already have the time when the lag was over the threshold in Zabbix, it's not clear why you need a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

In general you should avoid direct database connections and queries, you should use APIs.

For your specific need, you can use two possible solutions:

- implement [service monitoring](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/en/manual/it_services) and SLA for your triggers, then use the reports
- create a custom API script to check on a daily basis the [trigger](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/en/manual/api/reference/event/get) history, then use the trigger/recovery dates of every LAG event (you can have more than one daily!) to calculate how much time you where on LAG